# Stress Testing an AWS Web Application

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, web, backend, stress-testing

My company needs to do some stress testing and simulates hundreds of connections at the same time on our web application.

Our back-end is in Java, and hosted on AWS BeanStalk service.
I wanted to know if we can simulates connection on our own, or does AWS have a special tools to simulate connection ?

I saw Stress Testing vs Load Testing too, I can't tell the difference yet between those.
If someone have an answer, feel free to help me as I'm quite struggling here...

Thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I'm not aware of a specific tool to load test on AWS they do have a Solutions Implementation (https://aws.amazon.com/solutions/implementations/distributed-load-testing-on-aws/) which provides a template for distributed load testing.

If that seems a bit excessive for your needs I would recommend this article: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/using-locust-on-aws-elastic-beanstalk-for-distributed-load-generation-and-testing/

A basic way to describe the differences between load testing and stress testing is load testing would be simulating an expected load and measuring the performance whereas stress testing would be testing the system to its breaking point.

Comment: Thanks a lot I'll look into Locust to load test the application. I heard about WCAT too, developped by the iis team to load test website, i'll look at both of these solutions :) !